# I want to realize a function that receive the same parameters of std::bind and then call it, how?

Tags: c++

What I want to achieve is simple, like is:

```
template<class Fn, class... Args> void ui::addExecutable(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
        va_list argptr;
        va_start(argptr, fn);
        ToBeExecuted.push_back(bind<Fn, Args...>(fn, argptr));
}
```

and when I call it:

```
    addExecutable(helloWorld, "ME!");
```

the compiler said:

```
    undefined reference to `void cre::ui::addExecutable<void (&)(char const*), char const (&) [4]>(void (&)(char const*), char const (&) [4])'
```

I am not very familiar with template and did some google but didn't get a clue. So how can I realize the "addExecutable" correctly? Thank you!

In case you need, all the source code is [here](https://github.com/CoREse/creui).

Comment: Could you post the definition of ToBeExecuted?

Comment: @user3684240 The definition is the first code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have multiple problems here:

1. You get the linker error because you put the template into your `.cpp` file. Templates must usually be inlined.
2. You mix templates which are the C++ style of handling variable arguments with C style `va_start`/`va_list`. That does not work. In this case, you should stick to the C++ way and remove the first two lines in your function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are forgetting to specify argument list after function name in your invocation:

> template return-type name < argument-list > ( parameter-list ) ;

i.e.

> addExecutable<Fn, Class1, Class2>(helloWorld, "ME!");

Please see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template

Comment: It is not always necessary to specifiy this list. Especially in variable arguments templates, it is often omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing in C++ then you should better use C++ things like [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Here an example for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

// Collection of what you want to execute.
std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec;

// Add to the collection to be executed.
template<typename Fn, typename ...Args>
void addExecutable(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    vec.push_back(
            std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    );
}

// Execute everything in the collection.
void execute()
{
    for (auto& it: vec)
    {
        it();
    }
}

void helloWorld(std::string const& name)
{
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << std::endl;
}

void hello(std::string const& firstname, std::string const& lastname)
{
    std::cout << "Hello " << firstname << " " << lastname << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    addExecutable(helloWorld, "Me");
    addExecutable(helloWorld, "You");
    addExecutable(hello, "John", "Smith");

    execute();

    return 0;
}
```